# Why is the sin of Sodom in Genesis 18: 21 in singular 'sin', not 'sins'?

Tags: genesis

Genesis 18:20-21 please help me answer this question if you can .thank you

> And the LORD said, Because the cry of Sodom and Gomorrah is great, and because their sin is very grievous; I will go down now, and see whether they have done altogether according to the cry of it, which is come unto me; and if not, I will know. [Genesis 18:20,21 KJV]

Comment: Welcome to SE-BH. Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and functioning of the site. Generally, 'sin' is the propensity within which is the source and motive for 'sins', the actual acts of transgression. The word, here, in the original is חַטָּאָה _chattaah_ [Strong 2403](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/2403.htm).

Answer (score 1):

"Sin" is singular here because there was one particular sin that that warranted Sodom's destruction. Surprisingly, it was not the sin that took its name from from the city (sodomy). Ezekiel 16:49 tells us what this sin was. In this prophecy, God is warning Jerusalem:

> Behold, this was the sin of your sister Sodom: she and her daughters
> had arrogance, abundant food and careless ease, but she did not help
> the poor and needy.

Ancient Jewish writings preserve [several stories](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/13827-sodom) (perhaps exaggerated) about Sodom's evil treatment of the needy and travelers:

> In Sodom every one who gave bread and water to the poor was condemned
> to death by fire (Yalḳ., Gen. 83). Two girls, one poor and the other
> rich, went to a well; and the former gave the latter her jug of water,
> receiving in return a vessel containing bread. When this became known,
> both were burned alive (ib.).

Genesis Rabbah (l. 14) says that Lot had three more daughters in addition to the two who escaped Sodom with him. One of them, Peloṭet, was married to a man of Sodom. She secretly practiced hospitality, but being discovered by the city's people, she was sentenced to be burned. Sodom's judges were infamous for their cruelty in such matters. Thus, these injustices were not isolated acts by individuals or mobs but constituted sin of the city itself.

The treatment of Lot's guests confirmed the matter. Not only did the people of Sodom prevent Lot from offering hospitality to travelers, they demanded that his guests be brought out to be treated shamefully.

**Conclusion**: "Sin" is singular because the Sodom was destroyed for one particular sin: its hideous treatment of those in need, especially travelers.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is found throughout the OT and especially in the book of Leviticus, where, countless times, the justification for various laws, both purity laws and generosity laws is, "I am the LORD."  Here is a sample:

- Lev 11:44 - **I am the LORD** your God; consecrate yourselves and be holy, because I am holy. Do not make yourselves unclean by any creature that moves along the ground.
- Lev 18:5 - Keep My statutes and My judgments, for the man who does these things will live by them. **I am the LORD**.
- Lev 18:6 - None of you are to approach any close relative to have sexual relations. **I am the LORD**
- Lev 18:21 - You must not give any of your children to be sacrificed to Molech, for you must not profane the name of your God. **I am the LORD**
- Lev 18:30 - You must keep My charge not to practice any of the abominable customs that were practiced before you, so that you do not defile yourselves by them. **I am the LORD** your God.
- Lev 19:10 - Do not go over your vineyard a second time or pick up the grapes that have fallen. Leave them for the poor and the foreigner. **I am the LORD** your God.
- Lev 19:14 - Do not curse the deaf or put a stumbling block in front of the blind, but fear your God. **I am the LORD**.
- Lev 19:32 - Stand up in the presence of the aged, show respect for the elderly and revere your God. **I am the LORD**.
- Lev 19:34 - The foreigner residing among you must be treated as your native-born. Love them as yourself, for you were foreigners in Egypt. **I am the LORD** your God.
- Lev 20:26 - You are to be holy to me because **I, the LORD, am holy**, and I have set you apart from the nations to be my own.
- Lev 24:22 - You are to have the same law for the foreigner and the native-born. **I am the LORD** your God.’

It was no accident that the first of the 10 commandments is:

> Ex 20:2, 3 - I am the LORD your God, who brought you out of the land
> of Egypt, out of the house of slavery. You shall have no other gods
> before Me.

The Shema also sets this out clearly:

> Deut 6:4, 5 - Hear, O Israel: The LORD our God, the LORD is One. And
> you shall love the LORD your God with all your heart and with all your
> soul and with all your strength.

Habakkuk also write essentially the same thing which the NT quotes three times:

> Hab 2:4 - Look at the proud one; his soul is not upright - but the
> righteous will live by faith [in God]

Thus, when the Israelites kept the LORD as the center of their focus, they should have been non-racist, generous to the poor, kind, courteous, successful, sexually moral, etc, etc.

That is, the primary **sin [singular, Gen 18:20]** of the wicked cities was their willful ignorance of God and His righteous character.  This resulted in their hideous acts of hedonistic sexuality (the desire to pack-rape visitors to Sodom!!), their poor treatment of the poor and foreigners.

The same idea is greatly expanded upon in David's penitential Psalm 51 when he writes (inter alia)

> V4 - Against You, You only, have I sinned and done what is evil in
> Your sight

**APPENDIX - Israelite Covenant**

The purpose the Israelite Covenant (Ex 20:1-17) is stated clearly in Ex 19:5, 6 – to make the Israelites God’s peculiar treasure, his special/holy people, distinguished by the way they conducted themselves.  Ps 50:16-18, 74:20, 78:36, 37.

This purpose of the covenant was stated in other ways as, “I will take you as my own people, and I will be your God. Then you will know that I am the LORD your God, … ” Ex 6:7.  Now if you will indeed obey My voice and keep My covenant, you will be My treasured possession out of all the nations—for the whole earth is Mine.  And unto Me you shall be a kingdom of priests and a holy nation.’ Ex 19:5, 6.  See also Deut 7:6, 14:2, Isa 62:12, Lev 20:26, etc.  This is stated repeatedly: Lev 26:9-12, Deut 29:9-13, 2 Sam 7:24, 1 Chron 11:2, Ps 50:7, 95:7, 100:3, Isa 40:1, Jer 7:23, 11:1-4, 24:7, 30:9, 22, 31:1, 33, 32:38-40, Eze 11:20, 34:30, 31, 36:26-28, 37:23, 24, Hos 1:9, 4:6, Joel 2:26, 27, Zech 8:8.  It is significant that the first of the 10 Commandments is a decree to have only ONE God, the LORD, Ex 20:3, Deut, 5:7, 6:4-6.

This same idea is also expressed another way – creating a people who would be “called by the name of the LORD”, or, “called by my name”, 2 Chron 7:14, Isa 43:7, 65:1; that is, to bear the character of a gracious, loving, kind God.  The Jerusalem Temple was also a symbol of this covenant because it was “called by my Name”, 1 Kings 8:13, Jer 7:10, 11, 14, 32:34, 34:15.  Such people, God declared, “out of all nations you will be my treasured possession … a kingdom of priests and a holy nation.” Ex 19:5, 6.  See also Ruth 1:16.

Significantly, in Eze 36:16-38, the LORD sternly rebukes Israel because, “they profaned My holy name, because it was said of them, ‘These are the people of the LORD, yet they had to leave His land.’  But I had concern for My holy name, which the house of Israel had profaned among the nations to which they had gone. (v22, 23).  That is, Israel had profaned the name of God by sinning.

The Old Covenant was a matter of the “heart” (Deut 6:5, 10:12, 16, 11:18, Ps 40:8, Jer 24:7, 31:33, 34, 32:38-40, Eze 11:19, 18:31, 36:26) and NOT mere regulations (1 Sam 15:22, Ps 40:6-8, 51:16, 17, Prov 15:8, 21:3, Isa 1:10-17, Jer 6:3-6, 20, Hos 6:6, Micah 6:6-8).  These references make it clear that the Old Covenant did not really include the animal sacrifices, and that they could not define nor atone for sin. (Heb 9:9, 10:4, Ps 51:16, 17, 1 Sam 15:22).  The animal sacrifices and the sanctuary ritual were part of the Levitical covenant which acted as teaching device that anticipated, and was a type of, the High Priestly ministry of Messiah.

Answer (score 1):

Genesis 18:123-25, 32 NKJV

> 23 And Abraham came near and said, “Would You also destroy the
> righteous with the wicked? 24 Suppose there were fifty righteous
> within the city; would You also destroy the place and not spare it for
> the fifty righteous that were in it? 25 **Far be it from You to do such
> a thing as this, to slay the righteous with the wicked, so that the
> righteous should be as the wicked**; far be it from You! **Shall not the
> Judge of all the earth do right?”**

> 32 Then he said, “Let not the Lord be angry, and I will speak but once
> more: Suppose ten should be found there?”
>
> And He said, “I will not destroy it for the sake of ten.”

2 Peter 2:6-8 NKJV

> 6 and turning the cities of Sodom and Gomorrah into ashes, condemned
> them to destruction, making them an example to those who afterward
> would live ungodly; 7 and delivered righteous Lot, who was oppressed
> by the **filthy conduct of the wicked** 8 (for that righteous man,
> dwelling among them, **tormented his righteous soul from day to day by
> seeing and hearing their lawless deeds)—**

I'll present 2 ideas that this indicates:

**Collective Guilt:** The cities of Sodom and Gomorrah were collectively guilty of egregious wrongdoing. There is a long list of various sins and offenses **against God's moral law.** However, there was one simple collective sin: **unrighteousness.**

```
                    1 John 5:17 NKJV: All unrighteousness is sin...
```

**Unified Rebellion:** It's also possible that the singular "sin" reflects the unified rebellion and defiance of the inhabitants of Sodom and Gomorrah against God's righteous standards. Yes, there is a list of individual sins, but their collective rejection of God's moral law and refusal to repent constituted a single, overarching sinfulness.